# Перенос картинок и текста с одного таба на другой

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

В первом окне есть табы и в них можно добавлять картинки и текст, как сделать так, чтобы эти картинки автоматически загружались в табы(в табы с такой же позицией, что и в первом окне) другого окна, которое открывается по кнопке, находящейся в первом окне. Вот код, здесь реализовано вставка картинка и текста в выбранный таб первого окна
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QFileDialog, QInputDialog, QLabel, QApplication

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
 
class FirstForm(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    uic.loadUi('form1.ui', self)
    self.secondForm = SecondForm()
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.secondForm.show)
    self.secondForm.btn2_2.clicked.connect(self.addImage)
    self.secondForm.btn2.clicked.connect(self.addText)
 
  def getWidgetGeometry(self):
    try:
      x = int(self.secondForm.lineEdit.text())
      y = int(self.secondForm.lineEdit_2.text())
      w = int(self.secondForm.lineEdit_3.text())
      h = int(self.secondForm.lineEdit_4.text())
    except:
      x = 0
      y = 0    
      w = 100
      h = 100
    return QRect(x,y,w,h)
 
  def addImage(self):
    result = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.secondForm, 'Выбрать картинку', '')
    if result[1]:
      image = QImage(result[0])
      label = QLabel('', self.tab)
      label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
      label.setGeometry(self.getWidgetGeometry())
      label.show()
 
  def addText(self):
    result = QInputDialog.getText(self.secondForm, '', 'введите текст')
    if result[1]:
      label = QLabel(result[0], self.tab)
      label.setGeometry(self.getWidgetGeometry())
      label.show()
 
class SecondForm(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    uic.loadUi('form2.ui', self)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FirstForm()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Что такое табы?

Comment: QTabWidget, его виджеты